# Jquery toggle function breaks on pages that include mootools or slimbox script

Tags: jquery, null, mootools, toggle, slimbox

My friend is asked me to look over her site where there is an error on pages that use slimbox-- an unrelated Jquery toggle function breaks— here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".cat_nav dd").hide();
    $(".cat_nav dt").click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This code works fine when slimbox and mootools scripts are not present, but having either of those scripts load breaks it— the `dt` elements are not hidden and clicking on their respective `dd`s doesn't toggle them hidden. Here is the error message from Safari's JS console:

```
TypeError: Result of expression '$(".cat_nav dd")' [null] is not an object.
```

This error only appears on pages that load slimbox or mootools, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mootools.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slimbox.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Is there a way to compose this that is compatible with slimbox? She is using slimbox to display galleries on some pages that use this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) should help. Basically you need to call `noConflict` and use `jQuery()` to call your jQuery functions.

Comment: Yup, I use the suggestion of $j.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because of using `$(".cat_nav dd")`, you must use `$$(".cat_nav dd")`, because the `$()` function in mootools only take element id not CSS selector.